# Jenkins: Starting a build without permanently recording the result

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to tweak some options in my jenkins configuration, which is causing many builds to fail. I'd prefer to not keep these failures around in the build history, since they're not technically failures of the repository. In the past, I've just deleted the build after looking at the log, but this is a little tedious.

Is there a way to start a build with an option to not record the result of the build permanently?

Perhaps there's a URL that can be used to trigger a debugging build, somethign like:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?DEBUGGING
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "discard old builds" option in your job to only keep 1 build. If you have older builds you want to keep, you can give them the "keep this build forever" property. If you have a large number of jobs to work with, you can use the Configuration Slicing plugin to modify the Max # of builds to keep.